# How do I open a webview in another activity using editText for the url and a button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web1;
    EditText ed1;
    Button bt1;
    String Address;
    ProgressBar pbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                Address = "http://" + ed1.getText().toString();
                WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//below gives me this error stating new WebViewClient can not resolve.

```
                web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                web1.loadUrl(Address);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {


    WebView web1;

    String Address;
    String add;
    ProgressBar pbar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        web1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewActivity.WebViewClient());

    }


    public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
            web1.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android, you can pass the URL between activities.

Comment: Are you sure it can't resolve? You have an `import android.webkit.WebViewClient`, right?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't name **your** class as `WebViewClient` when there already is a conflicting name of `android.webkit.WebViewClient`

Comment: it crushes when i run it

Comment: Okay, so show the logcat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @MarkAcquaisie It can be important to provide the full text of the error message with your question, please try to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Intent to pass the url as string to the webview activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("URL",url)
startActivity(intent);
```

And Access it in WebViewActivity onCreate by:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String url = in.getStringExtra("URL");
```

Now pass this url in

```
weview.loadurl(url);
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;
EditText ed1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = ed1.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URL", url);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }
    });
}


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.mywebviewapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Here is a step by step implementation.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: @MarkAcquaisie make sure add internet permission and add activity in manifest file.

Comment: can you help me modify the example at tutorialspoint in order to make it load in another activity. thats all i seek. Am a fresher in android. @ Aayush Thakur

Comment: Thank you @ Aayush Thaku

Comment: Check the update. If this works for you do upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you @ Aayush Thaku